# Latin inscription on an ara

Tags: inscription

Can anyone help with this Latin inscription on a Roman Ara found in Valencia de Alcantara Spain?

modest us
cal uti
lari bus
a
v s l

Comment: Welcome to the site! Do you have a picture of the inscription? You can add one to your question if you [edit] it.

Comment: *Modestus* is likely the name of the dedicator. *Lari* and *bus* go together to form *laribus*, 'to the household gods.' *VSL* appears on other altars and is an abbreviation for *votum solvit libens*, 'willing(ly) fulfilled a vow.' One sometimes aso finds *VASL* and *VSLA*, where the A is short for *animo*; so it's possible that *AVSL* is another variation. In this case, those 4 letters means 'willing(ly) in mind fulfilled a vow.' Otherwise, perhaps the *a* is short for *aram*, 'altar'? (I don't recall seeing that before though.) That leaves just *cal* and *uti*, which possibly go together.

Comment: Actually, I think *Caluti* may be a form of *Calutium*, which is a place name. Depending on the date of the altar, I suppose the *a* could conceivably be short for *Augustiis*, modifying *laribus*, 'the Augustan lares.' I'm not sure how common it is to abbreviate that as just *a* though. I agree that a photo will be helpful, as will any other information that you can provide (e.g., a date).